# Casting object list which inherits type to new interface type list

Tags: c#, .net

For example imagine we have the following interface and class configuration:

```
public interface IAnimal 
{

}

public interface IDog : IAnimal
{

}

public class Animal : IAnimal
{

}
```

Then using the above configuration in an implementation like this

```
List<IAnimal> listOfAnimals = new List<Animal>();
```

I wish to cast it to List IDog with something like this:

```
List<IDog> listOfDogs = listOfAnimals.Cast()<IDog>.ToList();
```

I have also tried

```
List<IDog> listOfDogs = listOfAnimals.Cast()<IAnimal>.Cast()<IDog>.ToList();
```

**Is this possible, It could be possible I am not 100% sure if it can be done or not??**

Currently I recieve an InvalidCastException

Comment: I'm pretty sure that `List<IAnimal> listOfAnimals = new List<Animal>();` does *not* compile, because it would allow you to add a `Foo : IAnimal` to a `List<Animal>` (by executing `listOfAnimals.Add(myFoo)`), even though `Foo` is only an `IAnimal`, not an `Animal`.

Comment: What happened when you tried this code?

Comment: And what your list contains when you try to cast?

Comment: `listOfAnimals.Cast()<IDog>` is syntactially invalid. `listOfAnimals.Cast<IDog>()` will compile but fail at runtime if any list elements do not implement `IDog`. If you want to ignore those you can use `OfType`: `List<IDog> listOfDogs = listOfAnimals.OfType<IDog>().ToList();`

Comment: to clarify as maybe its a little confusing as you can see Animal class does not implement IDog however I thought it might be possible to cast an IAnimal implementation to an IDog as IDog inherits from IAnimal and I am lead to believe normally you can cast it like that

Comment: @Lee maybe you are answering this in that its not possible if any elements in the list do not implement IDog which in this case all elements do not implement it, I understand I can create a utility function or extension method to solve this but i wondered if I can just directly cast it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
List<IDog> listOfDogs = listOfAnimals.Cast<IAnimal>().Cast<IDog>().ToList();
```

This will only work if your `listOfAnimals` is actually `IDog`. I believe what you are looking for is `OfType`.

```
List<IDog> listOfDogs = listOfAnimals.OfType<IDog>().ToList();
```

Also note that your `()` and `<>` are reversed. Another thing to note is that any items that are not `IDog` will be ignored and not returned.

**Update from comment:**

> I am lead to believe you can cast both ways when dealing with
>   inheritance of interfaces etc..eg: IAnimal -> IDog and IDog -> IAnimal

This is true if all of the items implement `IDog`. You can go to and fro without issue. However, if you have an instance of `Animal`, you cannot go to `IDog` unless that animal actually implements `IDog`.

Imagine you had Animal, Dog, and Cat. Obviously Dog and Cat are both animals. They can easily go into anything wanting an Animal. However, you cannot explicitly give Animal to anything wanting a Dog or a Cat. For that you will need to cast upwards. The cast will succeed if the object is the correct type, but it will fail if you tried to turn a Cat into a Dog.

C# is a statically typed language. Even though there are no method signatures differing between Cat and Dog and the interface is empty, they are not the same thing.

```
public interface IAnimal 
{
}

public interface IDog : IAnimal
{
}

public interface ICat : IAnimal
{
}

public class Animal : IAnimal
{
}

public class Dog : Animal, IDog
{
}

public class Cat : Animal, ICat
{
}

Animal animal = null;
var dog = new Dog();
var cat = new Cat();

animal = dog; //Success
animal = cat; //Success
cat = (Cat)animal; //Success because animal is a cat.
dog = (Dog)animal; //Fail because animal is a cat.
//The above is the same as attempting to do:
dog = cat;
```

Comment: see my comment above the list is filled with Animal objects which implement IAnimal but not IDog, but I am lead to believe you can cast both ways when dealing with inheritance of interfaces etc..eg: IAnimal -> IDog and IDog -> IAnimal